# TypeScript: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'Assignable'

Tags: typescript

Having following script

```
class Assignable {
  constructor(properties: any) {
    Object.keys(properties).map((key: string) => {
      this[key as string] = properties[key]
    })
  }
}
```

Throwing this error

`Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'Assignable'.ts`

any idea why this is happening and how to fix it

Comment: `(key: keyof typeof properties)`

Comment: "*any idea why this is happening*" as the error message already says - `key` is `any`, and you cannot use it to index `Assignable`, since you need to do that a value that is a valid key for `Assignable`. And since `Assignable` doesn't actually have properties declared, there are no real valid keys (except built-ins like `toString`)

Comment: The key will be always a string if that is going to help

Comment: Also, unrelated - please don't use `.map()` for simple iteration. Use `.forEach()` or an actual loop.

Comment: I updated the example where key is a string

Comment: @AndonMitev you are still missing the fact that `Assignable` is not indexable by random strings. `key` needs to be an actual key for the object.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create the index on your class:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECCUEsDmA7MAjEBTaBvAUNEdANoDWWAngFzQQAuATgikgLq1gqUDc+hxYAHsUDRgFdg9IYwAUAB0ZD5WRvQRYInbgEo8A4sQDy6AFZYpAOgqUICpSrUaIOywDMZAUTDAAFrJtoAF4APn1DCOJ6XwQIcio2YOhFZVV1TXjKNgMIgF8dPkNc-FygA

```
class Assignable {
    [key: string]: any;

    constructor(properties: any) {
        Object.keys(properties).forEach(key => {
            this[key] = properties[key]
        });
    }
}
```